# Python regex: re.sub() enters enters new regex as string

Tags: python, regex

I am having a problem with Python's re.sub(). My aim:

- to interate through filenames in a for loop
- find regex1 (re1) in the filename
- replace with regex2 (re2)

I have tried the following:

```
import re

f_names = ["6000_3-22__data22_new.asc","99_23-2_B__report_22.pdf"]

re1 = r"[0-9]+_[0-9]+-[0-9]+_"
re2 = r"[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+"

for f in f_names:
    f = re.sub(re1, re2, f)
    print f
```

Which literally subs in the string for re2:

```
[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+_data22_new.asc
[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+B__report_22.pdf
```

What I would like to see returned is:

```
6000-3-22_data22_new.asc
99-23-2B__report_22.pdf
```

I have also tried using re.compile as a preliminary step, which gives the same result. 
Sure I must be missing something very obvious but cannot spot it. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)

```
>>> re1 = r"([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)_"
>>> re2 = r"\1-\2-\3"
>>> for f in f_names:
...     f = re.sub(re1, re2, f)
...     print f
...
6000-3-22_data22_new.asc
99-23-2B__report_22.pdf
```

**What it does?**

So basically when a pattern is enclosed in `()` paranthesis, the regex engine captures them and save them for later use. That is the substring matched in the first `()` will go into `\1` and so on

---

If you want a list, you can do it with [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) as

```
>>> [ re.sub(re1, re2, f) for f in f_names ]
['6000-3-22_data22_new.asc', '99-23-2B__report_22.pdf']
```

Comment: Nice fix for the regex, _but_ this won't change the values in the list. (I think that's what OP wanted) Maybe combine this with a list-comprehension?

Comment: @tobias_k Good point ! I have updated the answer with the list comprehension

Comment: Thank you, I made the changes and tried both the first option and also list comprehension, but get the following error on both:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\sre_parse.py", line 833, in expand_template
    raise error, "invalid group reference"
sre_constants.error: invalid group reference

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [groups](http://pythoncentral.io/more-about-python-regular-expressions/), and then use the captured groups to create your new filename.

See this example:

https://regex101.com/r/nO6rP3/1